# Preferred way of getting the selected item of a JComboBox

Tags: java, swing

HI,

Which is the correct way to get the value from a JComboBox as a String and why is it the correct way. Thanks.

```
String x = JComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

or

```
String x = (String)JComboBox.getSelectedItem();
```

Comment: It's a pity that `JComboBox` has a generic parameter but `getSelectedItem` is not using it,

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you have only put (non-null) `String` references in the JComboBox, then either way is fine.

However, the first solution would also allow for future modifications in which you insert `Integer`s, `Doubles`s, `LinkedList`s etc. as items in the combo box.

To be robust against `null` values (still without casting) you may consider a third option:

```
String x = String.valueOf(JComboBox.getSelectedItem());
```

Answer (score 6):

The first method is right.

The second method kills kittens if you attempt to do anything with `x` after the fact other than `Object` methods.

Comment: Well, the first method kills kittens on null-items. See my answer for the kitten-saving-solution ;)

Comment: @aioobe: Why do we care about `null` kittens? :)

Answer (score 3):

```
String x = JComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

will convert any value weather it is Integer, Double, Long, Short into text
on the other hand,

```
String x = String.valueOf(JComboBox.getSelectedItem());
```

will avoid null values, and convert the selected item from object to string

Answer (score 2):

Don't cast unless you must. There's nothign wrong with calling toString().

Answer (score 1):

```
JComboBox mycombo=new JComboBox(); //Creates mycombo JComboBox.
add(mycombo); //Adds it to the jframe.

mycombo.addItem("Hello Nepal");  //Adds data to the JComboBox.

String s=String.valueOf(mycombo.getSelectedItem());  //Assigns "Hello Nepal" to s.

System.out.println(s);  //Prints "Hello Nepal".
```

Comment: correction: at the last line of this answer "out" is only one time.

Comment: Hi, RamKrishna Thapa, welcome to [so]. If you want to make a correction to your answer, just click on the "[edit]" link under the post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Note this isn't at heart a question about JComboBox, but about any collection that can include multiple types of objects. The same could be said for "How do I get a String out of a List?" or "How do I get a `String` out of an `Object[]`?"

Comment: and this isn't an answer, its a comment.

Comment: Note that many people can't comment in this ridiculous system - "need X reputation".