# JComboBox string values are seen as null

Tags: java, netbeans

So I want to get the value of whatever the user selects from a jcombobox and just to be sure, when i run the program, i let the system print out what value it got.
However, it keeps giving me a null value even though I have chosen strings...

Here's the code..

```
String Country = String.valueOf(country.getSelectedText());

System.out.println("Country is "+Country);
```

Where country is the variable name of the JComboBox...
I expect it to show me the country that was chosen yet it just shows me "Country is null"

![showing null value when run](C:\Users\admin\Pictures\Camera Roll\country null.PNG)

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962416/preferred-way-of-getting-the-selected-item-of-a-jcombobox) could help you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preferred way of getting the selected item of a JComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962416/preferred-way-of-getting-the-selected-item-of-a-jcombobox)